# PostgreSQL - list all objects assigned to a role to remove objects and dele role

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to delete a role, but trying so I get the message that the role cannot be deleted because other objects depend on the role.

```
FEHLER:  cannot delete role  „name“, because other objects depend on the role 
DETAIL:  19 objects in database production
```

Later on  I will change the ownership the these objects through

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY old TO new;
```

but I would like to view these objects before. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to delete the roles. The objects the error message related to where not database records but privileges.
I could revoke the privileges with

```
revoke all on all tables in schema public from username;
```

It is important to log into the correct database after that

```
drop role username
```

removed the role